# Filtering JSON data with variable

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, es6-promise

So as it stands the data comes in and it is filtered to a certain day. For example:

```
data.Item.Tuesday
```

However I would like to be able to replace "Tuesday" with a variable that is declared elsewhere. I can't seem to find out what this filtering method is actually known as. Any advice is much appreciated!

```
getWeekData(UserId, weekNumber).then((data) => {
if (!data.Item || !data.Item.weekTotal) {
  console.log("Week Data Not Found");
} else {
  weekExercise = data.Item.weekTotal;
  dayTotal = data.Item.Monday;
  yesterdayTotal = data.Item.Tuesday;
  console.log("Week Total is: " + weekExercise);
  console.log("Todays Total is: " + dayTotal);
  console.log("Yesterdays Total was: " + yesterdayTotal);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `tuesday` with a variable by calling the object as you would an array:

```
const day_variable = 'tuesday'
data.Item[day_variable]
```